# VueJS place multiple .env in folder

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli

Hello I'm using VueJS 2 and I have multiple .env in my project.
My app have .env for each company to select the company configuration (skin color / files...)

Actually I have all my .env in the root folder:

```
.env.company1-dev
.env.company1-staging
.env.company1-prod

.env.company2-dev
.env.company2-staging
.env.company2-prod

.env.company3-dev
.env.company3-staging
.env.company3-prod
```

So when I'll get 20 companies it will be confused on my root folder so it is possible to create a folder where I can place all my .env ?

The idea :

```
/environments/company1/ 
    .env.dev
    .env.staging
    .env.prod
    
/environments/company2/ 
    .env.dev
    .env.staging
    .env.prod
    
/environments/company3/ 
    .env.dev
    .env.staging
    .env.prod
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your `vue.config.js` file you can add:

```js
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require("path");

let envfile = ".env";
if (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    envfile += "." + process.env.NODE_ENV;
}

const result = dotenv.config({ 
    path: path.resolve(`environments/${process.env.VUE_APP_COMPANY}`, envfile)
});

// optional: check for errors
if (result.error) {
    throw result.error;
}
```

the before run you can set `VUE_APP_COMPANY` to a company name and run your app,

> *Note:* It's important to put this code on `vue.config.js` and not in `main.js` because dotenv will use `fs` to read files.

### References

- https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path
- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/787
- https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. There is no way to do that without without using dotenv module ? Does dotenv will affect the vue cli build or I can keep what I have and just add your code?
What should I do with the result variable ?

Comment: I think that you does not even need to install `dotenv` because vue-cli already uses that to load .env files https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables; there is a section saying: `For more detailed env parsing rules, please refer to the documentation of dotenv`

Comment: I also edited to show usage of result, based on examples and docs I used to debug and show errors because dotenv load files inside a try catch

Comment: Ok I see, but I don't get this line `envfile += "." + process.env.NODE_ENV;` I have only production for this variable, I don't init for staging or other env like demo. The doc said : `NODE_ENV - this will be one of "development", "production" or "test" depending on the mode the app is running in.`

Comment: for the `VUE_APP_COMPANY ` I have to set this variable in the vue cli command ? e.g : `VUE_APP_COMPANY=company1 vue-cli-service serve --mode my-app-dev`

Comment: with this code yes, but you can configure the path of dotenv.config with javascript application logic too... using a environment variable is only a example

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer we have also used in the past. But I found a better solution to handle different environments. Using the npm package [dotenv-flow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-flow) allows not only the use of different environments but has some more benefits like:

- local overwriting of variables by using `.env.local` or `.env.staging.local` and so on
- definition of defaults using `.env.defaults`

In combination we have set up our projects with this configuration:

```
.env
.env.defaults
.env.development
.env.production
.env.staging
.env.test
```

And the only thing you have to do in your `vue.config.js`, `nuxt.config.js` or other entry points is

```js
require('dotenv-flow').config()
```

**Reference:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-flow

Comment: Your solution is good but this is not my main question. My problem was about the multiple .env by company and how can I change the default path to get my .env. The accepted answer reply to that. Your answer is about the different .env that you can have in your project. I think a mix of both answer cool be nice.

Answer (score 0):

**The powershell solution**

I was handling exactly the same problem. Accepted solution is kind of ok, but it did not solve all differences between companies. Also, if you are using npm, your scripts can look nasty. So if you have powershell, here is what I suggest - get rid of the .env files :)

You can keep your structure like you want in the question. Just convert the env files to ps1.

```
/build/company1/ 
    build-dev.ps1
    build-stage.ps1
    build-prod.ps1
    
/build/company2/ 
    build-dev.ps1
    build-stage.ps1
    build-prod.ps1
```

Inside each of those, you can fully customize all env variables, run build process and apply some advanced post-build logic (like careful auto-deploy, publishing, merging with api project, ..).

So for example **company1\build-stage.ps1** can look like this:

```
# You can pass some arguments to the script
param (
    [string]$appName = "company1"
 )

# Set environment variables for vue pipeline
$env:VUE_APP_ENVIRONMENT = "company1-stage";
$env:NODE_ENV="development";
$env:VUE_APP_NAME=$appName;
$env:VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL="https://company1.stage.mycompany.com"

# Run the vue pipeline build
vue-cli-service build;

# Any additional logic e.g. 
# Copy-Item -Path "./dist" -Destination "my-server/my-app" -Recurse¨
```

Last part is easy - just call it (manualy or from integration service like TeamCity). Or, you can put it inside **package.json**.

```
...
"scripts": {
    "build-company1-stage": "@powershell -Command ./build/company1/build-stage.ps1 -appName Company-One",
  }
...
```

The you can call whole build process just by calling

```
npm run build-company1-stage
```

Similary, you can create localhost, dev, prod, test and any other environment. Let the javascript handle the part of building the app itself. For other advanced work, use poweshell. I think that this solution gives you much more flexibility for configuration and build process.

P.S.
I know that this way I'm merging configuration and build process, but you can always extract the configuration outside the file if it gets bigger.